# load Bitmap with RGB_565 via Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

is there a way to pass either a bitmap-config or force this BitmapConfig? I would like to not do it via Transformation() as this would consume more CPU than needed and I am not sure if this is done before the cache ( my main reason to do this is that the images in the cache should not consume that much memory )

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found the solution - picasso 2.2.0 has now an API for this - was using 2.1.1 before and there was no API for this. Looks like this then:

```
picasso.load(url).config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(target);
```

Comment: I think loading image using RGB_565 in Picasso takes a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

I have found a nice solution, that works very fine and 100%
(Sorry but answer of @ligi not works for me])
Use this util class for any picasso bitmap changes (here is RGB565)
**Note** also that Picasso build singleton class
So this only changes will cover all others (also if you don't plan to use RGB565 everywhere)

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

public class Config565Transformation implements Transformation {

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);
        source.recycle();
        return resultBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return Config565Transformation.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

and simply use it

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .transform(new Config565Transformation())
    .into(imageView);
```

Reference: https://habrahabr.ru/post/218453/